# Is there a variation of goog.addSingletonGetter() for constructors with arguments?

Tags: singleton, google-closure, google-closure-library

I want to use `goog.addSingletonGetter()` (http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/4/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_testing_singleton.js.source.html#line56) to add a `getInstance()` method to a class with a constructor that accepts arguments:

```
Foo = function(x, y) {...};
```

Is there a way for me to specify `goog.addSingletonGetter(Foo, arg1, arg2)`? Calls to `Foo.getInstance()` would then lazily return the instantiated Foo object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Closure: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871)*** on page 70 defines `goog.addSingletonGetter()` as follows:

> For a class with **a constructor that takes zero arguments**, `goog.addSingletonGetter()`
>   adds a static method to its constructor function named `getInstance()` that returns the
>   same instance of that object whenever it is called. Generally, it should be used instead
>   of the constructor function if it exists.

One approach would be to create a singleton following the ***Instance in a Static Property*** design pattern presented in ***[JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752)*** on page 143 with the addition of a static `getInstance()` function.

```js
/**
 * @param {string=} opt_x
 * @param {string=} opt_y
 * @constructor
 */
Foo = function(opt_x, opt_y) {

  if(Foo.instance_) {
    return Foo.instance_;
  }

  /**
   * @type {string}
   * @private
   */
  this.x_ = goog.isDefAndNotNull(opt_x) ? opt_x : 'default_X';

  /**
   * @type {string}
   * @private
   */
  this.y_ = goog.isDefAndNotNull(opt_y) ? opt_y : 'default_Y';

  Foo.instance_ = this;
};


/**
 * Get the singleton instance of Foo.
 * @param {string=} opt_x
 * @param {string=} opt_y
 */
Foo.getInstance = function(opt_x, opt_y) {
  if (Foo.instance_) {
    return Foo.instance_;
  }
  return new Foo(opt_x, opt_y);
};
```

The advantage to using this pattern is that it protects you from accidentally constructing multiple instances in the event that someone were to write:

```js
var foo = new Foo();

... 
// thousands of lines later
var snafoo = new Foo(); // Returns the singleton instance.
```